# how to join multiple tables in mysql (can it be handled in php)?

Tags: php, mysql

There is a blog UI where I have to show name and picture of the user who posted the blog.And below that section I need to show the names of the people who are tagged in that post

tables are like this:-

**profile_tbl**

```
id      user_id      full_name       pic
```

----------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------+

```
 1        2031          xyz       img1.jpg
 2        4582          abc       img2.jpg
 3        104           user1     img.jpg
 4        3309          user2     aa.jpg
```

**blog_tbl**

```
id      creator_id      post_id       message      create_date
```

----------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+

```
 1        2031          21       my first post     2014-01-14 19:30:17
 2        4582          22       this is a test    2014-01-14 18:20:03
```

**tagged_users**

```
id      creator_id      post_id       tagged_user_id
```

----------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------------+

```
 1        2031            21             4582
 2        2031            21             104
 3        2031            21             3309
```

How to get this by a single query?
requirements:-
1.name of the user who posted this blog
2.picture of the user who posted this blog
3.use's name and id who are tagged in this post

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: SQL Joins. Research that

Comment: SELECT
 B.*,T.tagged_user_id,P.full_name,P.prf_pic
 FROM blog_tbl AS B
 INNER JOIN tagged_users AS T  ON B.post_id=T.post_id
 INNER JOIN profile_tbl AS P  ON T.to_id=P.user_id;

but this is not giving me the results I want it is repeating the same record.

Answer (score 0):

`blog_tbl` need to contain `user_id(current user id)` column so you can assign the author and also `tagged_users` need to contain `user_id(current user id)` so you know who tagged the person.

Comment: creator_id is serving that purpose in blog_tbl

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your data with a single query is

```
select `p1`.`first_nm`,`p1`.`prf_pic`,
`b1`.`crt_date`,`b1`.`desc`,
group_concat( distinct(`p2`.`first_nm`)) as `tagged_names`,
group_concat( distinct(`p2`.`my_id`)) as `user_ids`
from `my_profile` `p1`
Inner join `conversation` `b1` on `b1`.`creator` = `p1`.`my_id`
Left JOIN `notification` `t1` on `t1`.`creator` = `p1`.`my_id` 
Left join `my_profile` `p2` on `p2`.`my_id` != `p1`.`my_id` 
AND `t1`.`creator` = `p1`.`my_id` AND `t1`.`to_id` = `p2`.`my_id`
group by `p1`.`my_id`
```

This query will list all the tagged user names with comma separation and corresponding user ids with comma separation. So you can manipulate the result as you want

Here is the example I created

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72da55/14

Comment: @Abihk Chakraborty
Thanks a lot.. see can you please revisit that link I have created the actual schema.And run your solution. But may be I have done something wrong. It gives me the names of the users who is tagged along with the other names from profile table.See, I am not very good at it.

Comment: NO You have not done anything wrong, I was not eliminating data in the self join which is why it was showing all the users even if they are not tagged. I have updated the query and fiddle link check now if this is what you needed. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72da55/14